# Blazor Webassembly EditForm works on IISExpress but has Problem on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have a Blazor Webassembly Project that works fine on iisexpress (visual studio 2019). But when I deploy it on IIS, I can't see the login page due to this errors:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The provided expression contains a PropertyExpression which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.
> System.ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a PropertyExpression which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.ParseAccessor[String](Expression`1 , Object& , String& ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.Create[String](Expression`1 )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputBase`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetParametersAsync(ParameterView ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& , Int32 ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer , RenderBatchBuilder , Int32 , ArrayRange`1 , ArrayRange`1 )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder , RenderFragment )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
>
> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: No element is currently associated with component 13
> Error: No element is currently associated with component 13
> at e.updateComponent (https://localhost/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:31703)
> at t.renderBatch (https://localhost/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:12134)
> at window.Blazor._internal.renderBatch (https://localhost/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:61913)
> at Object.w [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:64435)
> at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost/_framework/dotnet.5.0.12.js:1:190800)
> at wasm_invoke_iiiiii (wasm://wasm/00aba242:wasm-function[5611]:0xdda7f)
> at ves_pinvoke_method (wasm://wasm/00aba242:wasm-function[5708]:0xdfb62)
> at interp_exec_method (wasm://wasm/00aba242:wasm-function[2155]:0x44c08)
> at interp_runtime_invoke (wasm://wasm/00aba242:wasm-function[7862]:0x12efff)
> at mono_jit_runtime_invoke (wasm://wasm/00aba242:wasm-function[7347]:0x118e5f)

. when I replace the EditForm with pure HTML inputs, everything is OK! here is my EditForm:

```
  <EditForm Model="request" OnValidSubmit="OnValid" style="max-width:500px;">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <ValidationSummary />
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="request.Username" placeholder="نام کاربری"></InputText>

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="fa fa-user input-group-text"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <InputText type="password" class="form-control" @bind-Value="request.Password" placeholder="رمز عبور"></InputText>

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="fa fa-lock input-group-text"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" disabled="@isDisabled">ورود</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <img src="dist/img/allin-logo.png" width="140" height="100" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            
            </EditForm>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
[Inject]
    public IAccountService accountService { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager navigationManager { get; set; }
    public AuthenticationRequest request { get; set; }

    private string message { get; set; }
    private bool isDisabled { get; set; }

    public Login()
    {
        
        request = new AuthenticationRequest();
      
        message = string.Empty;
        isDisabled = false;
      

    }


    private async void OnValid()
    {
        isDisabled = true;

        var result = await accountService.LoginAsync(request);

        if (result)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
        else
        {
            isDisabled = false;
            message = "نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه است";
        }


    }
```

what should I do?!

**Update:**
changing void OnValid() to Task OnValid() didn't solve the problem.

Comment: changed request to requestModel, get that errors again! :(

Comment: No element is currently associated with component 13 at e.updateComponent , does anyone has any information about this error? what does it mean?!

Comment: it's just Username and Password. two public string Properties. easyupload.io/u4g5sj you can download this sample project. go to /login page . it shows that error when I publish it on iis, but works fine when I run it in visual studio. EditForm is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Blazor *Webassembly* runs completely on the browser. The server version or edition plays no role at all. There's nothing wrong with either IIS or IIS Express.

The bug is using `async void` instead of `async Task`. Methods with the `async void` signature can't be awaited.

To fix it, change `async void OnValid` to `async Task OnValid` or even better, `async Task OnValidAsync`:

```
    <EditForm Model="request" OnValidSubmit="OnValid" style="max-width:500px;">
    </EditForm>

@code {
    private async Task OnValidAsync()
    {
        isDisabled = true;

        var result = await accountService.LoginAsync(request);
        ...

    }
}
```

The `async void` signature is *only* meant for asynchronous event handlers in desktop applications (WinForms, WPF). These frameworks were created before `Task` was introduced and don't know how to await asynchronous methods.

Asynchronous methods that return no results should use the `async Task` signature. Methods that return a value use `async Task<T>`.

Blazor on the other hand was built with asynchronous operations baked in. All Blazor examples use `async Task` instead. For example :

```
@page "/set-params-async/{Param?}"

<p>@message</p>

@code {
    private string message = "Not set";

    [Parameter]
    public string? Param { get; set; }

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.TryGetValue<string>(nameof(Param), out var value))
        {
            if (value is null)
            {
                message = "The value of 'Param' is null.";
            }
            else
            {
                message = $"The value of 'Param' is {value}.";
            }
        }

        await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman there's probably a Roslyn analyzer or Resharper rule already. Unfortunately, people routinely ignore warnings and analyzer messages.

Comment: actually it was Task OnValid(), I changed it to void to see if that's the problem! unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem! I still get that errors!

Comment: In that case post the *actual* code. The server doesn't matter. The real difference is that IIS Express is used for development, so any race conditions may not become apparent simply because the code is running slower than normal, with no latency when talking to the backend.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/u4g5sj you can download this sample project. go to /login page . it shows that error when I publish it on iis, but works fine when I run it in visual studio. EditForm is the root of the problem.

Comment: Post a minimal example in the question itself. Don't ask people to go to some random URL that may disappear after a while

Comment: @enet wrong. I didn't say that nor understand how you got to that conclusion.  It's the `async void OnValid` callback that can't be awaited

Comment: sorry, but I have posted almost the entire code in the question except the AuthenticationRequest model which is simply a Dto with string Username and Password Properties! you can try it yourself:  just add a RazorComponent to your app and add an EditForm to it! it doesn't work in my IIS and shows that error but works completely fine in visual studio!

Comment: @NimaMasghadi  the exception text says `The provided expression contains a PropertyExpression which is not supported.`. If you google for this you'll find [this similar issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39906) caused by Blazor version mismatches between the SDK used to create the application and the `global.json` on the production server. What are the versions on the dev and production machine?

Comment: @NimaMasghadi `async void` *is* a problem though. Since `OnValidSubmit` isn't awaited, the page may complete rendering before `LoginAsync` completes. This means `navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");` will get executed *after* the login page has finished rendering. The error message may not be shown unless you call `StatehasChanged`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `It's the async void OnValid callback that can't be awaited.` Exactly so, but still this is not and should not be the cause of: "The  bug is using async void instead of async Task. Methods with the async void signature can't be awaited."

Comment: @enet are you saying that using `async void` in a callback expecting `async Task` isn't a bug? Besides, the actual exception complains about something different. Adding `type="submit"` won't fix that. It will fix yet another of the code's bugs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: No, it isn't a bug, it's a bad practice in Blazor because the StateHasChanged method is not called from within an async method whose return value is void. It should be Task, so that the framework knows when or if the async call has completed.  I took the usage of bug in your answer as referring to the issue this question is about.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks a lot. You've made my day! I have a `RadzenButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit"` with its own `Click=@(args => DialogService.Alert("Some test here...", @success, new AlertOptions() { OkButtonText = "Close" }))`. My EditForm is something like `EditForm Model="@emailModel" OnValidSubmit="@SendOnlinePrescriptionRequest"`. The only way to get both events running is using `async Task`

Answer (score 1):

There was a mismatch between sdk versions. project was built with .net 5.0 but .net runtime was .net 6.0.1 . By uninstalling .net 6, everything works fine! Thank you for your helps!

Comment: And how exactly did you find it out ? Perhaps you provide some details or a link to reliable source that explain the issue, so that future generations  can benefit from it.