# Blazor WebAssembly IIS local

Tags: iis, blazor

I have blazor webassembly NET 6.0 with three projects (client, server, shared) and sql database.

Everything works when I run it from Visual studio on iis express.
When I publish it and configure to run on local IIS I get error

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

I tried lot of stuff, but nothing helps.

Comment: Since it works locally. That may be the reason for the .net version or IIS configuration. Here is a reference case for the same situation as you encountered. You can refer to the solution provided by the owner of this case. Check and select the appropriate .net version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73727667/blazor-webassembly-editform-works-on-iisexpress-but-has-problem-on-iis

Comment: did you install url rewrite on iis? https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
it is required in order to host blazor wasm on iis